# Fix whitespace in jQuery dialog box using CSS style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to display the jQuery dialog box using a CSS style, but I have a small bit of white space in the dialog box,

[image: White Space Problem]

**jQuery code:**

```
$('#success').dialog({
    //autoOpen: true,
    height: 180,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Add",
            click: function() {
                // Cancel code here
            }
        }
    ]
    //closeOnEscape: false,
    //open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui).hide(); }
    //closeOnEscape: false,
    //beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="popup-msg">
    <div id="loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
        <h3>Please wait a few seconds.</h3>
    </div>  

    <div id="success" title="Add To List" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <p style="padding:0;">User table is updated.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/915/)**

Do you have any suggestions for a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines to your CSS:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane
{
   margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this CSS:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/916/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of the plugin. You need to override the plugin classes

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane
{
margin:0px; 
}
```

I have give whole margin as zero instead of margin-top as left,right,bottom are already zero